# Highest values changes on vector

Tags: distance

I need a statistic or metric to obtain which vector has the highest changes between its values, I mean, I would like to get vector `b`, because it has different number contiguous to each other one. They don't have just binary numbers, maybe between 0-255 range:

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

As you can see, both vector has the same number of values and range, but different sequence. I had apply variance and coefficient of variation, but they give the same results.

```
print 'Var:', np.var(a),'CV:', np.std(a)/np.mean(a)
print 'Var:', np.var(b),'CV:', np.std(b)/np.mean(b)
Var: 0.25 CV: 1.0
Var: 0.25 CV: 1.0
```

What other statistic or measure I can try? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggested metric:
Let your metric be the mean of the absolute value of the "diff" of the vector, where diff is the vector with n-1 elements formed by taking differences of successive elements of the original n element vector.

With your example data, 
mean(abs(diff(a))) = 0.11111. mean(abs(diff(b))) = 1.

You could instead consider some other function of the diff if this is not exactly what you want.

Comment: A more general form is "norm of the difference".  Absolute value is one norm, but the L2-norm, all even positive L-norms, and the L-infinity norm are also acceptable.

Comment: @ EngrStudent , agreed. I thought of describing it as such, but decided to keep it non-technical, and indicate that variations were possible. I suppose I should have, so thanks for the comment.

Comment: There is great power in being able to describe it so your grandma would understand it.  My grandma is smart, but has no idea what an L-norm is.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you. Good solution, but see that it is affected when you have big differences between consecutive values, so I will modify it a little bit, just counting cases where they are different, then obtain their sum, and divide it by vector length.